# Can TFS 2010 build Agent run test?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

If so why should we use the architecture of test agent and test controller?

Comment: Well, you can run unit tests during a team build (in TFS2008).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what tests you are refering to. The build agent can run Unit Tests. However, in order to Run Coded UI Tests, or Web Tests those would be scheduled on a Test Agent.

Answer (score 0):

Only test agents can run tests.

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple build agents (and one controller) thus you can't do builds in parallel, is it the same for test agents? so you can have more than one test run going at the same time?